# Delete Multiple Users by there login ID in AEM using CURL

Tags: aem

I have the login id's of all the 500 users which need to be deleted from AEM 6.3 .

How can i do it by using curl command .

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: Users are in author environment, i tried few curl command but as i see curl command can only delete users individually .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `applyTo` request parameter](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#deleting-multiple-items) to remove multiple items through a single request.

To delete multiple users -

```
curl -u admin:admin -F":operation=delete" -F":applyTo=/home/users/geometrixx/charles.s.johnson@trashymail.com" \
    -F":applyTo=/home/users/geometrixx/carlene.j.avery@mailinator.com" http://localhost:4502/home/users
```

Try this on your local instance first, you might want to execute this in the publish instances as well to keep all the instances in sync. You can also use wildcard `\*` to delete all items under parent node.

Comment: Thanks for that.... One issue with that..

I have list of login ID's only in excel sheet, and I don't have the path of the users.

I want to know the curl command which I can use to delete multiple users without the need of knowing the path of users 

Because getting the path of 500 users will be some pain.

Comment: No worries i found the paths using aem-acs-commons.

Comment: no worries, happy to help, upvote and accept the answer for the benefit of others running into a similar issue. thanks.