# AEM- Execute Curl command multiple times fetching data from certain line in file

Tags: curl, aem

I need to delete a certain number of AEM users using curl .

The list of AEM users are in a excel sheet

Every time the curl command executes , it need to fetch the user data from certain line from the excel sheet .

To be precise ,

when the curl command executes for the 1st time, it should fetch the user data mentioned in the 1st row of the excel sheet

when the curl command executes for the 2nd time, it should fetch the user data mentioned in the 2nd row of the excel sheet

when the curl command executes for the 50th time, it should fetch the user data mentioned in the 50th row of the excel sheet

when the curl command executes for the 500th time, it should fetch the user data mentioned in the 500th row of the excel sheet

The platform is Linux .

Any help on how to achieve this would be really helpful. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking at writing a shell script to read data from excel, looping through all its entries and executing the below curl script for each entry.

```
curl -u admin:admin -FdeleteAuthorizable= http://localhost:4502/{{home/users/path}}
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686354/how-to-read-data-from-excel-sheet-in-linux-using-shell-script) to read excel data in a shell script.

---

Another options is using the `applyTo` parameter which allows [removing multiple items](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#deleting-multiple-items) via a single request.

cURL command to delete multiple users. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268564/4173416)

```
curl -u admin:admin -F":operation=delete" 
-F":applyTo=/home/users/geometrixx/harold.w.gavin@spambob.com" \
-F":applyTo=/home/users/geometrixx/iris.r.mccoy@mailinator.com" \
-F":applyTo=/home/users/geometrixx/zombie@mailinator.com" \
-F":applyTo=/home/users/geometrixx/sowmya" 
http://localhost:4502/home/users
```

Use an editor like notepad++ to append all the paths from your excel into the format the above cURL script accepts and execute the complete script in one go.

And it goes without saying, Try this on your local instance first, you might want to execute this in the publish instances as well to keep all the instances in sync.

Comment: Can you help in getting the exact command of fetching the user path from excel please.

Comment: I dont think its just one command, you'll have to code it to open the excel, go row by row and execute the delete command.

Comment: Please help in formulating the script for the same. Please help .

Comment: Why dont you try the second method using `applyTo`, that is far simpler .. all that you have to do is to format the excel data according to the query.